# Handle 2 conditions in if

Tags: android, if-statement

```
If(bool1&&bool2)

{    

//some  code

 } else{ 

 //some code 

   }
```

And here what I want is that even if 1 condition return true then also to proceed to run the code ***but*** I also want to know which condition returned true

**Edit**

I'm using RootTools library for checking root permission

```
RootTools.isRootAvailable() &&RootTools.isAcessgiven()
```

So if

```
RootTools.isAcessgiven() returns false
```

I can tell root is not proper but if

```
RootTools. isAcessgiven() returns true and RootTools. isRootAvailable () returns true
```

I can tell him root is proper

Comment: Unclear. Want to know how? You mean if only one is condition is true execute something different? Like `if(bool1&&bool2){
//some code
else if (bool1||bool2)
//someother code 
}else{
//some other code 
}`? (Note `If` is not valid Java, `if` is).

Comment: I'd use a switch statement rather than if for this purpose

Comment: I want to do that in if both values must be checked if also 1 returns true then to go forward with the same code and know which returned true

Comment: Then why check if both return true if you want to continue if only one returns true? What to check first?

Comment: Why down vote? Please explain

Comment: An edit is coming please wait

Comment: Edit added more info

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know which one returned true, you could just log it:

```
if (bool1 || bool2) {
    log.i("bool1: " + bool1 ", bool2: " + bool2)
    code......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

then you need two if statements.

```
if(bool1) {
    // code
} else if(bool2) {
    // slightly different code
} else {
    // final code
}
```

no way around it

Answer (score 0):

You mean proceed to run code "//someother code" ?

```
if(bool1 || bool2){
// fun first code for any of bool1 or bool2 - true
// you need to check which one was true - bool1, or bool2 in other statement.
} else {
// run this if bool1 and bool2 is false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one possible answer could be , Here both the if block will run .

```
if(bool1){
// some code
// print(in bool 1)
}
if(bool2)
{
// some code
// print(in bool 2)
}
```

The other answer you can do is my maintaining a another variable

```
boolean val1,val2;
if(val1=bool1 || val2=bool2 )
{

}
```